# Aurelia simple binding is not working

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a very simple binding which isn't working as I'd expect it to:

*app.js:*

```
export class PupilsViewer {

    pupilsInfo = [
        { name: 'John' },
        { name: 'Eric' },
        { name: 'Martin' },
        { name: 'Simon' }
    ];

}
```

*app.html:*

```
<template>
    <require from="./pupil"></require>
    <pupil repeat.for="pupilInfo of pupilsInfo" info="${pupilInfo}"></pupil>
</template>
```

*pupil.js:*

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Pupil {
    @bindable info = { name: 'unknown' };
}
```

*pupil.html:*

```
<template>
    <div>Name: ${info.name}</div>
</template>
```

This results in the following output:

> Name: unknown
>   Name: unknown
>   Name: unknown
>   Name: unknown

whilst I'd have expected:

> Name: John
>   Name: Eric
>   Name: Martin
>   Name: Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right now i had the same problem. it seems to be a typo-problem. try to change or remove camel-case for your bindables. but your binding is also not ok.

```
export class PupilsViewer {

    pupils = [
        { name: 'John' },
        { name: 'Eric' },
        { name: 'Martin' },
        { name: 'Simon' }
    ];

}
```

***app.html***

```
<template>
    <require from="./pupil"></require>
    <pupil repeat.for="pupil of pupils" info.bind="pupil"></pupil>
</template>
```

***pupil.js***

```
import {customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('pupil')
@bindable('info')
export class Pupil {

}
```

Comment: indeed, this will be fixed in a release within the next two days. though